# Remove Iframe for client app part

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a popup in my client app part, right now it shows in the iframe for the app part.

Is it possible to remove the iframe?

Comment: App Parts render in iframes, it is how they work. If you do not want to embed the app part in to a page, you can link to the application page URL directly

Comment: Ok, okey. I use the default.aspx for installation. The other page, that i use my client app part for is to show a popup from the lists that have been installed on my default.aspx Right now, the popup shows in the iframe, i want it to show on the whole site.